# How to boxplot the summary of and data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have a data frame containing 80 different features.
Using `summary(data)` I can see the min max and average of each column. What I know would like to do is visualise these with a plot.

I would like to be able to see the min max range of each column as well as the mean. The goal is it to be able to visual see outliers and the range of the data. I tried using a box plot to do so, but I am unable to find the right way to plot it.

Any Help is appreciated. I already got the summary in a data frame doing the following:

```
summary <- as.data.frame(apply(data[,2:(ncol(data)-1)],2,summary))
```

Preview of the Data:

```
    f1  f2  f3  f4
1   1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   0   1
5   0   0   0   0
6   2   1   0   0
7   2   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0

structure(list(feat_1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), feat_2 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), feat_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), feat_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share some of your data using `dput()`.

Comment: Hey martin, just added the data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my attempt using `reshape` and `ggplot`

```
  df <-structure(list(feat_1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), feat_2 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), feat_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), feat_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Load packages

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
```

melt the data frame

```
df.melted <- melt(df)
```

use ggplot, here `alpha` is the transparency and to get the mean use `stat_summary` with `fun=mean`

```
ggplot(df.melted,aes(factor(variable),value,fill=variable))+
geom_boxplot(alpha=0.6)+
stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point",shape=21,size=3)
```

Output:

[image]

see `?ggplot` for more details